# is there an API/specification about the google docs "native" format?

Tags: google-docs

or, Can i create/modify google docs by 3rd application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does not share info on their native, proprietary format--possibly called "kix" according to [this StackExchange answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/65548/94408).

You CAN programmatically create, modify and destroy Google Drive document files in 3rd party apps (or build your own) by manipulating *representations* of those files exposed by various Google APIs and scripting services.  It took a bit of truffle-hunting through the online documentation, but I did find a description of the structure of a Google Doc here: [Extending Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#structure_of_a_document).

Again, this is a description of a *representation* of the file, not the file itself.